# Custom Post Type Instances All Use Same Featured Image (The First)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type in Wordpress defined in `functions.php` in the following manner:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'my_custom_post_type' ));


function my_custom_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('MyCustomPostTypes', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('MyCustomPostType', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New MyCustomPostType'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit MyCustomPostType'),
        'new_item' => __('New MyCustomPostType'),
        'all_items' => __('All MyCustomPostTypes'),
        'view_item' => __('View MyCustomPostType'),
        'not_found' => __('No MyCustomPostTypes found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No MyCustomPostTypes found in the trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'MyCustomPostTypes'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'MyCustomPostType Here',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive' => true,
    );
    register_post_type('my_custom_post_type', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_type');
```

When I create the first instance of `MyCustomPostType`, everything looks great. So does every subsequent instance--*except* that the Featured Image on all these subsequent instances is the same as the first. All of the other data are correct, and the Featured Image displayed in the Edit MyCustomPostType view of the page is correct. So I am really confused.

I'm looping through the instances like this:

```
<?php
    while ($my_custom_post_types->have_posts()) {
       $my_custom_post_types->the_post();
?>
       <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

When I display the particular post (*i.e.* the target of `the_permalink`), I'm doing so like this:

```
<section id="content" role="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1><?php single_post_title(); ?> </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <figure>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>                                                              
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 text">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But as I said, this call retrieves the Featured Image for the chronologically first instance of `MyCustomPostType` in every case.

Any insight into the problem or what I should be looking at in the `wp_posts` table is appreciated.

Comment: the featured images are stored in the post_meta table. It sounds like a loop issue, i assume you are having this issue on the archive page?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know which table. I found that the data in the tables are accurate--the posts are indeed linked to the right thumbnails. So I am still confused why the code is fetching the wrong image. Meanwhile, I added more detail to my question to show how I am looping.

Comment: sorry do you mean that the issue is on the single post view? Or is it on the archive list of posts? If it is on the single post view, can you show the code?

Comment: The issue is in the single post view, and the code has been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1><?php single_post_title(); ?> </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <figure>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>                                                              
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 text">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>          

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This should work, you need to do a loop on the single page as well for `the_post_thumbnail()` to work without a post id

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks for your patience and your help.